# Is $dist(A,B) = dist(cl(A), B)$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am not sure whether this is necessarily true, however I wasn't able to find a counterexample where it doesn't hold.

How can I proceed to prove that $dist(A,B) \leq dist(cl(A), B)$ and $dist(cl(A), B) \leq dist(A,B)$?

Since $A \subseteq cl(A)$ I think we could state that $dist(cl(A), B) \leq dist(A,B)$. What about the other inequality?

Comment: You have to use that $cl(A)$ is the set of limit points of $A$. Also, there will be an $a_0\in cl(A)$ with $dist(a_0,B)=dist(A,B)$.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality for that: for each limit point $a$ of $A$ s.t. $d(a, b) \leq r$, you have $a^\prime \in A$ with $d(a, a^\prime) < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, hence $d(a^\prime, b) \leq r + \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, which just means $\operatorname{dist}{(A, B)} \leq r$. Try applying the properties of infimum on inequalities to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since we define the distance between sets as $d (X, Y) = \inf \{ d (x, y) | x \in X, y \in Y \}$.

As you already showed, $d ({\rm Cl} A, B) \le d (A, B)$ because $A \subseteq {\rm Cl} A$ is true for any set $A$.

To show that $d (A, B) \le d ({\rm Cl} A, B)$, consider any point $x \in {\rm Cl} A$. By definition, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $B (x, \varepsilon)$ intersects $A$; i.e., there exists $a_{x, \varepsilon} \in A \cap B (x, \varepsilon)$. By Triangle Inequality, for any $b \in B$, $d (a_{x, \varepsilon}, b) \le d (a_{x, \varepsilon}, x) + d (x, b)$. But $a_{x, \varepsilon} \in B (x, \varepsilon) \implies d (x, a_{x, \varepsilon}) = d (a_{x, \varepsilon}, x) < \varepsilon$. This shows that $d (a_{x, \varepsilon}, b) < d (x, b) + \varepsilon \implies d (a_{x, \varepsilon}, b) < d (x, b)$. This is enough to show that $d (A, B) = \inf \{ d (a, b) | a \in A, b \in B \} \le d ({\rm Cl} A, B) = \inf \{ d (x, b) | x \in {\rm Cl} A, b \in B \}$, as desired.

Comment: What if we are in a discrete space and $A = (0,1), B = [1,2]$? 
We have $d(A,B) = 1$ because $d(a,b) = 1 \  \forall a \in A, b \in B$. But $d(cl(A), B) = 0$ since $1 \in cl(A) \land 1 \in B$. In this case it isn't true that $d(A,B) \leq d(cl(A), B)$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @peterfizza Not true. In the discrete topology, $A$ (and indeed, every other subset of $\mathbb{R}$) is closed. So $1 \notin {\rm Cl} A$.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Thanks for the clarification.